# Static equilibrium problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque, equilibrium, statics

I am designing a balanced-arm lamp structure for a robotics project and I obviously want the lamp to stay on its base without falling when the arm is extended. For that, I applied the conditions for static equilibrium and I come to an equality (relation between the masses and the distances of the base, head, arm, etc. of the lamp) that ensures that the angular acceleration is 0. So far I am sure that my reasoning is correct, but I think that the result I got is not what I am looking for. Experiencing with a real lamp or with every similar object in general you can apply a certain weight to the arm before the lamp starts falling. So experience and common sense tells me I should arrive to an inequality, but I don't know how to get there. Can somebody offer some light to the subject?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want as an answer, especially since you have given so little details of what your problem is and how you solved it.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. And it's a question, so obviously at the time I  didn't know the answer, so I don't understand how you expect that I tell you how I solved it. Your arrogance is not welcomed, and if you couldn't provide an answer to the question it would have been better if you didn't comment anything. People like you discourage everyone else to learn and ask questions. Anyways I found the answer thanks to a professor in my university's physics department.

Answer (score 1):

[Balanced-arm lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced-arm_lamp) typically have a heavy and wide base. If you take moments about the edge of the base (which would be the fulcrum if the lamp tipped) then the idea is that the large weight at the centre of the base multiplied by its small moment arm is greater than the weight of the lamp holder multiplied by its large moment arm. To find the approximate maximum horizontal distance that the lamp holder can be extended, divide the weight of the base by the weight of the lamp holder, and multiply by the radius of the base. For a more accurate calculation you will need to take into account the weight of each arm, which you can assume acts through its mid-point.

An alternative design is to use a counterweight. Again, the idea is that a heavy weight with a smaller moment arm counterbalances a smaller weight with a larger moment arm. But this time the counterweight can be extended beyond the edge of the base. A mechanical linkage can move the counterweight out by an appropriate distance as the lamp holder arm is extended.

Comment: Yes I have I thought in a lot of different designs to implement. However, I made some calculations and calculating the torque at the edge of the base for the worst case scenario, and considering the border case where N = 0, I arrived to the conclusion that the torque of the weights that are to the left of the axis of rotations must be greater than the torque of the forces that are acting on the right of this point. I arrived to a relation between the masses and the distances of the system and I am confident of my result. What do you think?